# I can see my extension installed in php extensions in wamp but the program does not run?

Tags: php, installation, wampserver, php-extension, ta-lib

I found a small program that I found on stackoverflow to test the trader_sma() function but i get an error.I can see **php_trader** installed in php extensions in wamp controller.

How can I resolve this issue and get php_trader get working on my machine?

```
<?php
    $real = array(12,15,17,19,21,25,28,12,15,16);
    $timePeriod = 3;
    $data = trader_sma($array,$timePeriod);
    var_dump($data);
?>
```

**Link 1:** [Wamp Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mjivj.png)
**Link 2:** [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CDk1.jpg)

Comment: Did you check the error logs to see if that extension loaded properly?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It shows something like this:PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: trader: Unable to initialize module

Comment: Well there you go. The extension never actually get loaded.

Comment: What version of WAMP, Apache and PHP are you using

Comment: I am asking because it is likely the extension you found is not compatable with the current version of PHP you are running

Comment: @RiggsFolly 3.0.6

Comment: And PHP? And is it 32bit or 64bit

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is showing 32 Bit But I installed 64 bit version from WAMP Site!

Comment: You mean the extension is 32bit OR WAMPServer is 32bit?

Comment: @RiggsFolly It is 64 Bit!

Comment: And what version of PHP are you using?????

Comment: @RiggsFolly My php is 32 Bit so I installed 32 Bit Version of Php trader and I get this in error_log %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Comment: I am now completely confused. You said your WAMPServer was 64bit, so how can you be using a 32bit PHP. If WAMPServer is 64bit, so are Apache/MySQL and PHP

Comment: You will need the Thread Safe version of the extension, denoted as `-ts-` to work with a WAMPServer configuration

Comment: And the extension must also match your version of PHP i.e. 5.6 or 7.0 or 7.1

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understood that and now I am back with previous version of php trader and I am running 64 bit PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Issue Solved Thank You So Much!